# UDK Modular construction (customisable vehicles etc)

Tags: 3d, udk

I'd like to build an interface whereby the user can attach various components and blocks onto a vehicle, this is then saved (as object/coordinate, rotation, scale values - in database) and can be used again later.

After looking into sockets I haven't been able to find a way of saying `connect ObjectA's SocketOne to ObjectB's SocketX with rotation Z and Scaling V` for instance.

If that sounds infeasible to you (which it may well be), is there another way of scripting 2 objects to be "joined", so they act as one item when they move/animate?

```
   Create ObjectA at 0,0,0
   Create ObjectB is at 10,0,0
   ObjectA.link(ObjectB)
```

I would like the sub objects to still be animated etc (like meshes connected to sockets can)

If anyone has any pointers they would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Martin